# JPanel refresh issue with game

Tags: jpanel

i am making a LAN command based game, and i am currently parsing structured english to java. i have parsed everything and i can draw to a grid, but i can only hard code text to the grid before runtime and cant seem to get the grid to refresh with new text.

Parsing Class:

```
public class ServerPlayerParsing {    
ServerGridGenerator serverGrid = new ServerGridGenerator (10, 10);
public String validate(String command){
serverGrid.frameGen(); 
if (wordCount(command)== 3) { 
    String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
    commandParsing(commandArray);
} else {
    System.out.println("Error! Format incorrect!");
    System.out.println("Correct format = [COMMAND 1] [COMMAND 2] [COMMAND 3]");
}
return "";
}
public  int wordCount(String command){
String[] commandCount = command.split("\\s");
return commandCount.length;
}
public  String commandParsing(String[] commandArray) {
switch (commandArray[0]) {
case "move":
secondCommand (commandArray);
break;
default: System.out.println("Error in first command!");
}        
return " ";
}
public String secondCommand (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[1]) {
case "forward":
forwardMovement(commandArray);
break;
case "backward":
backwardMovement (commandArray);
break;
case "left":
leftMovement (commandArray);
break;
case "right":
rightMovement (commandArray);
break;
default: System.out.println("Error in second command!");
} 
return " ";
}
public   String forwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[2]) {
     case "1":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(1);
     break;
     case "2":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(2);
     break;
     default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
    }
return " ";
}
public   String backwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[2]) {
     case "1":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(1);
     break;
     case "2":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(2);
     break;
     default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
    }
    return " ";
}
public   String leftMovement (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[2]) {
     case "1":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(1);
     break;
     case "2":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(2);
     break;
     default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
    }
    return " ";
}
public   String rightMovement (String commandArray[]) {
switch (commandArray[2]) {
     case "1":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(1);
     break;
     case "2":
     serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(2);
     break;
     default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
    }
return " ";
}
}
```

Grid Generator class:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ServerGridGenerator extends JFrame {
public int serverPlayerXPos = 0;
public int serverPlayerYPos = 0;
public int clientPlayerXPos = 0;
public int clientPlayerYPos = 9;
public int endXPos = 9;
public int endYPos = 5;
int row = 10;
int column = 10;
int sizeGrid = 700;
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];

public void frameGen(){
ServerGridGenerator frame = new ServerGridGenerator(row, column);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public ServerGridGenerator(int r, int c) {
squareButtons = new JButton [r][c];
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c));
for(int y=0; y<c; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<r; x++) {
         squareButtons[y][x] = new JButton("");
         squareButtons[y][x].setOpaque(true);
         squareButtons[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
         squareButtons[y][x].setEnabled(false);
         pane.add(squareButtons[y][x]);
     }        
}
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
        squareButtons[clientPlayerYPos][clientPlayerXPos].setText(" P2");
        squareButtons[endYPos][endXPos].setText(" END");
}

 public void serverPlayerMoveRight (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos + 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveLeft (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos - 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveForward (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos + 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveBackward (int moveBy){
     for (int i=0; i<moveBy; i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos - 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
      }
 }
```

My issue is that i can draw the first " P1", " P2", " END" but then when the parser calls the methods for moving forward, backward, left, right but it doesnt draw on the grid, can you help explain why this happens and what i can do to fix this?

Thanks for your time

**=================================================================================**

**EDITED:**

I have realised what im doing wrong and i need to call the movements within the gridGenerator/constructor method. i have changed the code and hard coded a value and it works, but now i need to make the parser call the drawing methods from the constructor and im having trouble with that. could you please help me call draw the movements like the following example but instead of hard coding the values i need them to be got from the parser.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class ServerGridGenerator extends JFrame {
public int serverPlayerXPos = 0;
public int serverPlayerYPos = 0;
public int clientPlayerXPos = 0;
public int clientPlayerYPos = 9;
public int endXPos = 9;
public int endYPos = 5;
int row = 10;
int column = 10;
int sizeGrid = 700;
JButton[][] squareButtons = new JButton [row][column];
//public ServerPlayerParsing serverpc = new ServerPlayerParsing();

public void frameGen(){
ServerGridGenerator frame = new ServerGridGenerator(row, column);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
}

public ServerGridGenerator(int r, int c) {
squareButtons = new JButton [r][c];
Container pane = getContentPane();
pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c));
for(int y=0; y<c; y++){
    for (int x=0; x<r; x++) {
         squareButtons[y][x] = new JButton("");
         squareButtons[y][x].setOpaque(true);
         squareButtons[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
         squareButtons[y][x].setEnabled(false);
         pane.add(squareButtons[y][x]);
     }        
}
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
        squareButtons[clientPlayerYPos][clientPlayerXPos].setText(" P2");
        squareButtons[endYPos][endXPos].setText(" END");
        serverPlayerMoveRight(6); // <============ Hard coded value
}

 public void serverPlayerMoveRight (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<(moveBy+1); i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos + 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
        repaint();
        validate();
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveLeft (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<(moveBy+1); i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerXPos = serverPlayerXPos - 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveForward (int moveBy){
    for (int i=0; i<(moveBy+1); i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos + 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
    }
 }
 public void serverPlayerMoveBackward (int moveBy){
     for (int i=0; i<(moveBy+1); i++) {
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" ");
        serverPlayerYPos = serverPlayerYPos - 1;
        squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
      }
 }
 public void timeDelay (){
    try {
        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch(InterruptedException ex) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: with the above example "validate" never gets called. So is that the answer to your problem?

Comment: have you tried ebugging the code?

Comment: a lot depends if you are on the Event Dispatch Thread or not. So it is pretty important to have a runnable example, otherwise we can only speculate

Comment: if you can strip down the code, and have it in a runnable form, then you should get an answer. I put a public static void main() on the ServerGridGenerator but i dont know if its meant to be there. For example : just have the method serverPlayerMoveRight() without left forward back. It makes it easier for us. otherwise we cant see the forrest for the trees.

Comment: @OliverWatkins i changed the code and now know how to draw but now i need help moving on and making the parser choose the correct methods but through the gridGenerator method. any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are thinking at this point, your original approach would work if you take out the frameGen method, move the code to set the frame visible to the constructor of the grid frame.  Then your parser is sending commands to the visible frame and it should work.  What we don't see is your **main** method.  I'd suggest you take a step back and look at your design, figure out what is in control, draw out the flow on paper, the re-implement to follow that flow.  Somewhere you need to link the parser and the grid and start them both running.

Comment: I've been trying to figure this out for the last few days, I'm really stuck and I'm not sure how to fix it. I tried to re implement it but I can't get it to work how I want it to. I don't have a main method because this grid is part of a larger program and the grid is called so it doesn't need a main, but I tried to implement it and it doesn't even compile. Could you please help me and explain how to do it and what I should do, with examples of lines of code would be great. Thanks I really appreciate your help

Comment: See my edited answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I think is that you are actually creating multiple instances of your frame but only seeing one of them.  Inside your driver class you have the following code:

```
public class ServerPlayerParsing {    
     ServerGridGenerator serverGrid = new ServerGridGenerator (10, 10);
     public String validate(String command){
         serverGrid.frameGen(); 
         if (wordCount(command)== 3) { 
            String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
            commandParsing(commandArray);
         } else {
            System.out.println("Error! Format incorrect!");
            System.out.println("Correct format = [COMMAND 1] [COMMAND 2] [COMMAND 3]");
         }
         return "";
     }
```

Notice how you create the ServerGridGenerator as a class level object then inside the validate command you are calling **serverGrid.frameGen()**.  **frameGen** has this code:

```
public void frameGen(){
   ServerGridGenerator frame = new ServerGridGenerator(row, column);
   frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
   frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   frame.pack();
   frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

So everytime you call the **validate** method are creating another instance of the ServerGridGenerator frame and making that frame visible.  See if when you execute multiple commands if you are getting multiple frames being created.

Also noticed that the instance you create as **serverGrid** is never being shown, but that is the instance that is receiving the movement commands.

**=====EDIT in response to request for example=====**

Starting with your originally posted code for ServerGridGenerator, I made the following changes to the constructor only, the rest was left as-is:

```
public ServerGridGenerator(int r, int c) {
   squareButtons = new JButton [r][c];
   Container pane = getContentPane();
   pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(r, c));
   for(int y=0; y<c; y++){
       for (int x=0; x<r; x++) {
           squareButtons[y][x] = new JButton("");
           squareButtons[y][x].setOpaque(true);
           squareButtons[y][x].setBackground(Color.white);
           squareButtons[y][x].setEnabled(false);
           pane.add(squareButtons[y][x]);
       }        
   }
   squareButtons[serverPlayerYPos][serverPlayerXPos].setText(" P1");
   squareButtons[clientPlayerYPos][clientPlayerXPos].setText(" P2");
   squareButtons[endYPos][endXPos].setText(" END");

   /*****     ADDED THESE LINES *******/
   setPreferredSize(new Dimension(sizeGrid, sizeGrid));
   setLocationRelativeTo(null);
   pack();
   setVisible(true);
}
```

and I completely deleted the method **frameGen** as it is unnecessary.  Then in the ServerPlayerParsing code, inside the **validate** method I removed the call to **serverGrid.frameGen()** since it is no longer present.

To test the code, I added a main to ServerPlayerParsing and an input loop to accept commands but otherwise left that code intact:

```
import java.io.*;

public class ServerPlayerParsing {

    /*** NEED A MAIN TO TEST THE CODE ****/
    static public void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       ServerPlayerParsing td = new ServerPlayerParsing();
       td.go();
    }

    /***** PROVIDES A SIMPLE USER PROMPT/INPUT LOOP FOR TESTING ****/
    public void go() throws Exception {
      DataInputStream cin = new DataInputStream(System.in);
      boolean running = true;
      String line;

      while(running) {
        System.out.printf("> ");
        line = cin.readLine();
        line = line.trim();
        if(line.length() == 0) continue;
        if( line.equalsIgnoreCase("EXIT") ) {
            running = false;
            continue;
        }
        System.out.println("Validate: " + validate(line.toLowerCase()));
      }
      System.exit(0);
   }

   /***** THE BELOW IS ALL YOUR ORIGINAL EXCEPT FOR THE frameGen CALL ***/
   ServerGridGenerator serverGrid = new ServerGridGenerator (10, 10);
   public String validate(String command){
     /** NO LONGER NEEDED   serverGrid.frameGen();   */
    if (wordCount(command)== 3) { 
      String[] commandArray = command.split(" ");
      commandParsing(commandArray);
    } else {
      System.out.println("Error! Format incorrect!");
      System.out.println("Correct format = [COMMAND 1] [COMMAND 2] [COMMAND 3]");
    }
    return "";
  }
  public  int wordCount(String command){
    String[] commandCount = command.split("\\s");
    return commandCount.length;
  }
  public  String commandParsing(String[] commandArray) {
    switch (commandArray[0]) {
      case "move":
        secondCommand (commandArray);
        break;
      default: System.out.println("Error in first command!");
    }        
    return " ";
  }
  public String secondCommand (String commandArray[]) {
    switch (commandArray[1]) {
       case "forward":
          forwardMovement(commandArray);
          break;
       case "backward":
          backwardMovement (commandArray);
          break;
       case "left":
          leftMovement (commandArray);
          break;
       case "right":
          rightMovement (commandArray);
          break;
       default: System.out.println("Error in second command!");
    } 
    return " ";
  }
  public   String forwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
     switch (commandArray[2]) {
       case "1":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(1);
         break;
       case "2":
         serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(2);
         break;
       default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
      }
      return " ";
   }
    public   String backwardMovement (String commandArray[]) {
       switch (commandArray[2]) {
         case "1":
            serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(1);
            break;
         case "2":
            serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(2);
            break;
         default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
       }
       return " ";
   }
    public   String leftMovement (String commandArray[]) {
       switch (commandArray[2]) {
          case "1":
             serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(1);
             break;
          case "2":
             serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(2);
              break;
          default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
       }
       return " ";
    }
    public   String rightMovement (String commandArray[]) {
       switch (commandArray[2]) {
          case "1":
            serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(1);
            break;
            case "2":
              serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(2);
              break;
              default: System.out.println("Error in third command!");
        }
        return " ";
    }
  }
```

This code by itself will work as you intended, but as I can't see the rest of your code I don't know how your **main** is interacting with the parser class.

The code also could be cleaned up quite a bit.  For example, instead of passing a string to all of the various **move...** methods and switching on the value you could parse the 3rd command array element using **Integer.parseInt()**.  If the parse is successful the value is an integer, otherwise the command is bad.  Then you could eliminate all of the move functions and handle that in the **secondCommmand** method like this:

```
public String secondCommand (String commandArray[]) {
  int steps = -1;
  try {
    steps = Integer.parseInt(commandArray[2]) ;
  } catch(Exception ex) {
    steps = -1;
  }
  if( steps == -1 || steps > 2) {
    System.out.println("Error in third command.");
  } else {
    switch (commandArray[1]) {
      case "forward":
        serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveForward(steps);
        break;
      case "backward":
        serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveBackward(steps);
        break;
      case "left":
        serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveLeft(steps);
        break;
      case "right":
        serverGrid.serverPlayerMoveRight(steps);
        break;
      default: System.out.println("Error in second command!");
    }
  }
  return " ";
}
```

Comment: i created the frame and the grid in one constructor method and it works, and the parse works too, but im having other issues. thanks for your help though, ill try and fix them

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a `pane.repaint()` at the end of each serverPlayerMoveX method

Comment: I don't have access to a decent Java editor now, I'll check again tonight if nobody's answered by then.